# How to put a PS3 super slim hard drive into a new console?

Tags: ps3, hardware, hard-drive

My PS3 Super Slim bricked beyond repair, and i really wanted to find a way to salvage all the data inside its hard drive so i could possibly use it in a new PS3 if i ever buy another one. My console doesn't even get turned on anymore, so no safe mode can be involved. I searched for some info and learned that the PS3 data is heavily encrypted, so i can't just slide the drive into a new console, it apparently demands formatting the drive beforehand. Is there any way to avoid this from happening? Maybe clone the contents of the old console into the new console's built in drive? Maybe "tricking" the console into thinking there's nothing out of the ordinary?

Comment: Depends how the disk is encrypted. If the data is encrypted using a key that is shared among all PS3s, you could just slot the old drive into the new PS3. But if each PS3 has its own unique key, the new PS3 won't be able to read the old data unless you decrypt that data first and then re-encrypt it using the new PS3's key. Sadly, I have no idea how to do that.